# Random dentro de Random

Tags: php

```
<?php
// Define um array com alguns sites:
$site[] = 'site1.com';
$site[] = 'site2.com';
$site[] = 'site3.com';
$site[] = 'site4.com';

// Escolhe um valor aleatório (respeitando o total de sites)
$destino = rand(0, (count($site) - 1));

// Redireciona o usuario:
header("Location: " . $site[$destino]);
?>
```

Olá, eu estou usando essa função para que quando o user acessar esse php, ele seja redirecionado para um desses sites. Mas que queria fazer um random dentro de um random. Por exemplo: Na primeira opção seria site1.com e site2.com. Ai na segunda opção site3.com e site4.com.

De forma que se for selecionado aleatoriamente a primeira opção, seria aberto aleatoriamente o site1 ou o site2.

Answer (score 1):

Vou te explicar melhor, primeiramente você vai criar uma variável chamada $grupo que será um array dentro desse array você criara mais dois array cada um contendo 2 sites.

```
$grupo = [ 
    [ 
        'site1', 
        'site2' 
    ],

    [
        'site3',
        'site4'
    ]
];
```

Pense assim você possui o grupo  A e esse grupo possui dois valores dentro dele A1 e A2

Para imprimir esse valor

```
// Aqui estamos acessando o primeiro array e acessando o segundo valor dele 'site2'

echo $grupo[0][1];            


// Aqui estamos acessando o segundo array e acessando o primeiro valor dele 'site3'

echo $grupo[1][0];
```

Como o seu intuito é que eles retornem isso de forma aleatória basta adicionar a função rand() no lugar do identificador de chave do array.

```
echo $grupo[rand(0,1)][rand(0,1)];
```

Aqui ele irá acessar o array aleatoriamente e retornaram um de seus valores também aleatoriamente.

Estude arrays multidimensionais isso será essencial, qualquer dúvida comenta ai qualquer coisa.

Comment: Cara, to meio na duvida quanto ao funcionamento desse codigo ai, vc teria como explicar?

Comment: Fiz uma explicação mais completa, qualquer dúvida chame blz

Comment: Desta forma estaria correto? http://prntscr.com/my30pt

Só para você entender. Eu tenho 5 link1s. 3 são mais importantes e 2 menos importantes. Então quero priorizar os 3 link que deixei separado e os 2 menos importantes em um unico espaço, assim os 2 links menos importantes tem menos chances de serem vistos. Se puder conferir o codigo e ver se ta certo, eu agradeceria demais, cara.

Comment: Nesse caso você terá que efetuar uma checagem para verificar quantos itens existem dentro do grupo antes. 

Caso seja mais de um valor você utiliza o rand() e deixa que ele decida qual valor deve ser retornado mas caso contenha somente um valor você retorna ele.